# UK visa received back without documents

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I applied for a UK tourist visa from India for myself, my wife and 2 kids. My brother, his wife and 2 kids also applied along with us.
Good news - we all received the visa in 8 days.

For myself and my family we got only the application forms back. But my brother and his family got all documents submitted along with the application form.

Why did I not get my docs back?

There is no way to reach VFS in Mumbai. They diverted me to some email ID, which responded with an auto mail and then some, which said I will be charged for the inquiry. Isn't it their mistake if they forgot to send my docs back?

Suggestions on what to do?